# Gridview multiple checkbox selection

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.8

I want to check multiple item checkboxes without clicking on the checkbox, rather than on other clicking columns.

Here is my **.cs code

```
private void gridView2_RowClick(object sender,DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridView2.GetSelectedRows().Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (int i in gridView2.GetSelectedRows())
            {
                gridView2.SelectRow(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

And, this is my **.designer.cs code

```
this.gridView2.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;
this.gridView2.OptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMultiSelectMode.CheckBoxRowSelect;
this.gridView2.OptionsSelection.ShowCheckBoxSelectorInGroupRow = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
```

Comment: Not clear if you want a button outside of the gridview that you click, and it selects all checkboxes for you, or if you want the user to click ANY place on the row or the check box to select the check box.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I am sorry that I couldn't make it clear. But you are right. If I click ANY place on the row or the check box to select the check box.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming a gridview?

We have this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"  />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check Test" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnClick="MyCheckBoxClick(this);"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <script>
            function MyRowCheck(ctrl) {
                MyCheckBox = document.getElementById(ctrl);
                MyCheckBox.checked = !MyCheckBox.checked
            }

            function MyCheckBoxClick(ct) {
                ct.checked = !ct.checked
            }

        </script>
```

code to load:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 12 * from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
                     new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {

            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox MyCheckBox = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "MyRowCheck('" + MyCheckBox.ClientID + "');";
        }
    }
```

So, we just attach a ROW click to the grid.

We get this output:

[image]

this works fine and a click on the row will toggle the check box.

but, the PROBLEM is then if you actually click on the check box. The Row click fires toggles the check box, and then the check box click ALSO fires and un-does what you just did!!

So, I added the on-click event to the check box - and we just toggle the setting again, and we are good to go.